# Access SharePoint data via ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Custom Widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget, sharepoint

I need to read and write data from/to SharePoint site via ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Custom Widget. Does anybody any experiences how to do it? I tried SharePoint REST API and putting a code from this documentation [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx) to my widget but I can't get to SharePoint.